# Сохранение выбранной картинки и ее автоматическая загрузка при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку open открывается галерея, после чего imageView отображает выбранное пользователем изображение.
Это работает, но как сделать, чтобы это изображение сохранялось, и автоматически подгружалось при запуске приложения?
Я нашел способ, но мне не удается встроить его конкретно в этот код:

```
package com.dennysnumb.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button open;
    ImageView photoRegistration;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saved = sharedpreferences.getString("path", "");
        photoRegistration = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        photoRegistration.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(saved)));

        open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opgalbtn);
        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1234;
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1234:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    ImageView photoRegistration = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    photoRegistration.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                    String pathData = selectedImage.toString();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("path", pathData).apply();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как у вас картинка будет в галерее и после закрытия приложения, я бы советовал вам сохранять не картинку, а путь к ней. Дальше при запуске приложения, вам просто нужно будет взять сохраненный путь и оттуда достать картинку. Чтобы сохранить путь, можно использовать [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). При выборе картинки берете путь и сохраняете его в памяти. Перед функцией `onCreate()` делаете глобальную переменную:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences
```

дальше в функции `onCreate()` эту переменную инициализируете:

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

дальше в функции `onActivityResult` добавляете этот код:

```
String pathData = selectedImage.toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("path", pathData).apply();
```

в качестве данных для сохранения берем то что возвращает intent:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
```

и дальше при загрузке приложения в функции `onCreate()` берете путь из памяти:

```
sharedpreferences.getString("path", "")
```

И дальше уже все то же самое что вы делаете при выборе картинки через диалог. [Вот](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) туториал как работать с настройками. Возьмем ситуацию, когда пользователь удалил картинку из галереи. Чтобы приложение работало и дальше без сбоев, можно сохранить картинку в папку приложения, куда пользователь доступа чаще всего не имеет. Это делается так:

```
File source = new File(imageReturnedIntent.getData().toString());
File destination =  getFilesDir();
try 
{
 FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и теперь у вас есть как-бы резервная копия вашей картинки на случай ее удаления из галереи. Вот интересные [статья_1](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/), [статья_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409137/android-copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another) которые будут полезны при решении вашей проблемы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android

Comment: он у вас хранится в sharedPreferences вам его просто нужно оттуда взять и все

Comment: `photoRegistration.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(saved )));` должно по логике быть так

Comment: фух, так вы виджет не инициализировали, у вас программа не понимает куда ей картинку сетить

Comment: у вас в коде все есть уже, в функции `onCreate()` добавьте этот код `ImageView photoRegistration = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);` и вообще можно сделать глобальную переменную ImageView photoRegistration и потом просто ее инициализировать photoRegistration = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Comment: если вы на эмуляторе запускаете, то зайдите в папку data->data-> имя пакета приложения и там будет папка sharedPrefs и там посмотрите на переменную которую вы сохранили, что там написано

Comment: по-моему так можно посмотреть и на реальном устройстве, просто давно не пробовал подключаться поэтому не уверен, попробуйте если ничего не получится вывести в логи эту переменную `Log.i("some_tag",saved )` и посмотреть что выведется

Comment: сразу после того как вы получаете переменную saved, мы же ее хотим посмотреть

Comment: Туда добавил, получил примерно следующее: W/ImageView: Unable to open content: file:///content%3A/media/external/images/media/8267

Comment: Еще это:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/8267 (No such file or directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169485/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-a-uri-or-any-storage - тут написано понятно вроде бы что да как сделать чтобы получить и сохранить путь

Comment: а в самом коде нормально все?

Comment: с первого взгляда все нормально, но если картинка не тянется с сохраненного пути, значит сохраняется не то что нужно. И от этого нужно плясать)) вот есть вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546101/get-real-path-for-uri-android где описано как вытащить путь к файлу

Comment: Если брать, к примеру, вот это, то как можно этот код адаптировать под мой? Uri file_uri = Uri.parse(videoURI); // parse to Uri if your videoURI is string
String real_path = file_uri.getPath(); // will return real file path

Comment: у вас есть onActivityResult там обрабатывайте по примеру из вопроса

Comment: Один вопрос, касательно возможности создания резервной копии в папке приложения на случай, если пользователь удалит фото из галереи. Добавил это к себе в код, однако Android Studio почему-то не распознает copyFile в строке  FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);

Comment: а FileUtils подчеркнуто красным или подтянулось нормально?

Comment: Нет, не подчеркнуто. Я же правильно понял, что это надо вставлять в onActivityResult?

Comment: вы это можете добавить где вам нужно копировать файл, можно в отдельную функцию выделить например. Вот есть туториал на java https://www.journaldev.com/861/java-copy-file где есть разные варианты копирования файла

Comment: Почему-то ни один из этих методов мне не подошел, думаю это у меня руки кривые) Те, что пытался выделить как отдельную функцию, их потом не получалось вызвать